# How to create a Data generator for an image segmentation model?

Tags: python, file, image-processing

I am working on an image segmentation problem. There are 3 types of images in my dataset(Drishti_GS). One is raw fundus image and the other two are soft map images namely optic cup seg and optic disc seg. I am trying to make a data generator for which I can train my model on. I am attaching the screenshot of names of images I got after using the following code.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
      if filename.endswith(".png"):

        print(filename)
```

[image]

I need to load these images. I hope that someone can help me with some concrete codes or some useful materials.

Answer (score 0):

You can load images by:

```
for image_name in os.listdir("data_path"):
    image = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('data_path/'+image_name, color_mode='rgb', target_size=(128,128))
    names = image_name.split('_')
    if names[-1]=="cupsegSoftmap.png":
        label = ...
    elif names[-1]=="ODsegSoftmap.png":
        label = ...
```

You can manually set what the label value should be, as an array

Comment: Instead of splitting, you can also use `str.endswith` to check if the end of the string is equal to something: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith